# Distinct query optimization

Tags: mysql, sql

I have used the "Distinct" clause in my sql query, but have faced the performance degrade issue. It takes more time than expected in querying the database.

I have Google'd and found that distinct clause can sort the table.

My question is if there is any other way is enhance the query, either by modifying the query such that output should be same, or any other suitable way.

**My query is simple as:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT a,b,c,d,e FROM table_test WHERE a LIKE '12%' AND((b = 'ABC') OR (c = 'ABC'));
```

Note that i have created index on a, b, c also.

Comment: Using `OR` made it slow, alternatives may help.

Comment: My query is such like that i have to consider 'a' and either 'b' or 'c'.
Anyway OR Clause does not make any difference.Main concern is Distinct clause

Comment: One of `OR` alternative - that I'm not sure is faster - is using `UNION`, and another one is using a `temp table` that you insert data based on `b` next insert data based on `c` and then return that `temp table` - in a sp -.

Comment: Yes `union` can help here instead of `or`

Comment: Can we apply union on single table?as here 'a','b','c' are the attributes for the same table 'table_test'.
Can you modify the above query with Union?

Comment: How many rows are in the resultset? What are the column types? Anyway, this seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you have duplicates in the result set?

Comment: There are millions of row in the result set.Cloumn types are VARCHAR.There are duplicate entries because we have only different combination for attribute 'a' 'b' 'c'.So there may be case when we have same tuple with (a and b) and with (a and c).So we have duplicate entries.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
SELECT a,b,c,d,e 
    FROM table_test 
    WHERE a LIKE '12%' AND b = 'ABC'
UNION 
SELECT a,b,c,d,e 
    FROM table_test 
    WHERE a LIKE '12%' AND c = 'ABC'
```

Comment: Yes,But in execution plan its doing the similar thing as distinct(i.e sorting).And execution time is same as earlier.